# reading dynamically added input values into an array php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

Every thing is working expect that on adding the dynamic fields,the input added is not captured into the array.Only the values in the only created input are read. HTML PART

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" >
<thead>
    <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price (Ksh.) </td><td>Qty</td><td> (Ksh.)</td></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product[]" required="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" required/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="linetotal[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Product" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            Grand Total: Ksh.<input type="text" name="grandtotal" readonly="readonly" /><span id="grandtotal"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

THE javascript to sum up the get the sub total and grand total is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 1;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    counter++;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="linetotal' + counter + '" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);

    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
});

$("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"], input[name^="quantity"]', function (event) {
    calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    calculateGrandTotal();
});

$("table.order-list").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    calculateGrandTotal();
});
});
function calculateRow(row) {
var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
var qty = +row.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();


var linetotal = +row.find('input[name^="linetotal"]').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
}
function calculateGrandTotal() {
 var grandTotal = 0;
 $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="linetotal"]').each(function () {
    grandTotal += +$(this).val();
});



$("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

the php part to read the array is

```
if(isset($_POST['cinvoice']) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" &&is_array($_POST["product"]) && is_array($_POST["quantity"]) && is_array($_POST["price"]) && is_array($_POST["linetotal"]))

{

$recordid="";
$firstname="";
$product="";
$quantity="";
$price="";


$linetotal="";


foreach ($_POST["product"] as $key => $prod) {


 $product .= $prod.",";
}

foreach ($_POST["quantity"] as $key => $qty){ 



 $quantity.=$qty. ",";

}

   foreach ($_POST["price"] as $key => $prc) {



$price.=$prc. ",";

}

foreach ($_POST["linetotal"] as $key => $linetotal) {

  $linetotal.=$linetotal. ",";
}
```

Comment: you have to declare the name in array format. For example ` name="product[' + counter + ']"'

Comment: By the way, you can save lines for the 3 foreach like so : `$product = implode(',', $_POST["product"])` etc...

Comment: yes. you declared name in array format in htm part(ie, `product[]`) and in javascript you used name as a string (ie `product' +count + '`)

Comment: @FairyDancer no need to pass count in name :)

Answer (score 0):

you should pass textbox name as an array:

```
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product[]"/></td>';
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]"/></td>';
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]"/></td>';
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="linetotal[]" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Also you can use implode function in php

```
foreach ($_POST["product"] as $key => $prod) {
 $product .= $prod.",";
}
```

to

```
$product = implode(',', $_POST["product"])
```

Comment: Thanks. However, passing the textbox as an array still does not change anything.